# Unreachable code detected, variable in if statement

Tags: c#, variables, if-statement, for-loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < numOfHours; i ++)
{
    for (int a = 0; a < NUM_DAYS; a ++)
    {
        Color colour;
        if (NUM_DAYS == SATURDAY)
        {
            //It says that this is unreachable
            colour = Color.LightBlue;

        }
        else 
        {
            colour = Color.White;
        }
        SolidBrush fill = new SolidBrush(colour);
        Pen outline = new Pen(Color.Black);
        paper.FillRectangle(fill, a * apptWidth, i * apptHeight, apptWidth, apptHeight);
        paper.DrawRectangle(outline, a * apptWidth, i * apptHeight, apptWidth, apptHeight);

    }
}
```

I am not sure why it will not change the color variable.  I have set up a calander that will draw out a grid depending on how many hours they have in a day, so the rows will be the hours they have and the coloumns will be the amount of days.  I want to change the color of the box that will represent saturday.  Thank you in advanced.

Comment: What type is `SATURDAY`? This code is unreachable, because your `if` is never getting true.

Comment: Is `NUM_DAYS` a constant? Probably you want to check `if (a == SATURDAY)`

Comment: yep, definitely `a` instead

Comment: If this answered your question, please click the checkmark so it is moved off the Unanswered list.  If it helped, click the upvote button to help others find good answers.  See [Tour]

Answer (score 3):

Presumably both `NUM_DAYS` and `SATURDAY` are constant, so the expression in your if statement always return false (as it seems they're not the same).

I think you meant:

```
if (a == SATURDAY)
```